# Converting to matlab time

Tags: matlab, timestamp

I have strings of the format '15:10:21' for time, and I also know the date, which is in the format 2011-08-05.

What's the best way to obtain matlab time (in days since 1900) out of this data?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`datenum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datenum.html):

```
>> num = datenum('2011-08-05 15:10:21')

num =

   7.3472e+05

>> datestr(num)

ans =

05-Aug-2011 15:10:21
```

The "matlab time" is actually days since the 0th of January, in the year 0:

```
>> datestr(0)

ans =

00-Jan-0000
```

Comment: date = 2011-04-05     time = 08:30:04 but strcat(date, ' ', time)
ans = 2011-04-0508:30:04 How do I insert space between them?

Comment: `str = [date ' ' time];` should do it.

Comment: You can also protect blanks inside `strcat` calls by putting them in cells, like this: `strcat(date, {' '}, time)`. Strcat will deblank chars, but not cellstrs.

Comment: @nibot: you can help the function by explicitly specifying the format string: `datenum(str,'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS')`

Comment: If date is a single date, and times is a vector, how can I get a vector of strings res such that res(i) = [date ' ' times(i)]? I would like to be able to do this in one line

Comment: @Trup: the protected `strcat` form will work; `[ ... ]` will not. Strcat is "vectorized" to work with arrays, and will "scalar-expand" the non-array inputs. E.g. `date = '2011-08-15'; time = {'00:01','00:02','00:03'}; res = strcat(date, {' '}, time)`